# Spring @Autowired gives null in a @Repository bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple standalone application using @Autowired to inject a SessionFactory, here is the code:

```
package au.edu.rdsi.rexportal;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("rexportalConsole")
public class RexportalConsole {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("development");
        ctx.load("classpath:META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        RexportalConsole rc = (RexportalConsole) ctx.getBean("rexportalConsole");
        System.out.println(rc);
        System.out.println(rc.sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

When I run this program I always get null for sessionFactory property:

```
au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@1f3a1de9
null
```

But if I change @Repository to @Component, I get the correct result and I can use the sessionFactory bean:

```
au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@14eb7ad0
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6fcbf86a
```

I want to use @Repository because I need the translation of exceptions as you can see in my application.xml, the PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor works for @Respository:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="au.edu.rdsi.rexportal" />

<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<beans profile="production, qa, staging">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="rexportalDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/rexportalDS" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="rexportalDS" />
        <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:au/edu/rdsi/rexportal/domain/**/*.hbm.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="development, test">
    <bean id="rexportalDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rexportal" />
        <property name="username" value="password" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="rexportalDS" />
        <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:au/edu/rdsi/rexportal/domain/**/*.hbm.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true"</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Am i missing something? Why @Component works here but @Respository?

Here is the log when I use @Repository:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@6f3a342a: startup date [Sun Apr 13 00:31:30 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'rexportalDS' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@37cae761: defining beans [messageDao,rexportalConsole,messageService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,rexportalDS,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@3a3248be
null
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@6f3a342a: startup date [Sun Apr 13 00:31:30 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@37cae761: defining beans [messageDao,rexportalConsole,messageService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,rexportalDS,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

And log when I use @Component:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@2c683bfc: startup date [Sun Apr 13 00:42:43 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'rexportalDS' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d600a0c: defining beans [messageDao,rexportalConsole,messageService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,rexportalDS,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@26d6221b
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@34592e88
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@2c683bfc: startup date [Sun Apr 13 00:42:43 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d600a0c: defining beans [messageDao,rexportalConsole,messageService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,rexportalDS,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: Your configuration as you posted it here works just fine with @Repository. I've quickly tested it in a simple project, replacing the Hibernate SessionFactory with another foo class. The issue may be somewhere else in your application. Are you, by any chance, instantiating the SessionFactory manually (with 'new' operator)?

Comment: What's actually in `META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml`?

Comment: @Andrei, As you saw in my code,to use spring DI, I call ctx.getBean. The thing here is that \@Autowired works if I use \@Component, or \@Service. Only \@Repository does not work.

Comment: @Sotirios, Sorry I made a typo, the META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml is what I posted here. The name I post should have been "spring-rexportal", not "application.xml"

Comment: Can you post the complete logs, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field access is breaking when the exception translation proxy wraps the `rexportalConsole` bean. Otherwise `@Autowired` would be throwing a fit.

Take a look at this

```
@Component
//@Repository
public class RexportalConsole {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("postconstruct this:" + this);
        System.out.println("postconstruct this.sessionFactory:" + this.sessionFactory);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("development");
        ctx.load("classpath:META-INF/spring-rexportal.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        RexportalConsole rc = (RexportalConsole) ctx.getBean("rexportalConsole");
        System.out.println("main rc:" + rc);
        System.out.println("main rc.sessionFactory:" + rc.sessionFactory);
        System.out.println("main rc.getSessionFactory():" + rc.getSessionFactory());
        // rc.fail();
    }


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    public void fail() {
        throw new SQLGrammarException("foo",null);
    }
}
```

produces

```
postconstruct this:au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@7e3e1a61
postconstruct this.sessionFactory:org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1f361707
main rc:au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@7e3e1a61
main rc.sessionFactory:org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1f361707
main rc.getSessionFactory():org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1f361707
```

Swapping the annotations to use `@Repository` produces this

```
postconstruct this:au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@79e893ae
postconstruct this.sessionFactory:org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1437c309
main rc:au.edu.rdsi.rexportal.RexportalConsole@79e893ae
main rc.sessionFactory:null
main rc.getSessionFactory():org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1437c309
```

There's probably something super-obvious I'm missing as to why this is happening, like the proxy is proxying the getter method and just returns null on direct field access, but I'd have to dig in to figure out why.

At any rate, your wiring does work.

***Update***: Another answer suggested that the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` is redundant. This isn't the case. If you uncomment the `rc.fail()` line in the code above, you will see a Hibernate `SQLGrammarException` when you comment out the `PostProcessor` bean, and a Spring `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` when you include it. The proxy that wraps the `@Repository` and does exception translation is only created if the `PostProcessor` is declared. And it's that proxy that breaks field access, likely by hiding the field. You can read up about it in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) in section 14.2.2.

Comment: "something super-obvious I'm missing" => good job finding / realizing this. It is indeed super obvois. Proxy classes are proxying method calls. You can not proxy direct field access. +1 for the answer

Comment: It's that proxy that prevents directly accessing fields - make sense, as long as I use getter, it just works.

Comment: @PavelHoral Yes I know that, the part I'm missing is why the proxy doesn't blow up on direct field access.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia that is a good point. If `proxy-target-class` is enabled (which is a MUST if the class does not have any interface), the proxy is just a dynamic **subclass** of the target class. That is why it works and why the field is uninitialized.

Answer (score -3):

Try autowiring session factory as below:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this will change?

Comment: spring uses "magic" for autowired stuff.  you can autowire without a setter.